# Javascript create object with property as dynamic objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, object

I tried a lot  searching and didnt get desired solutions.

What I want to achieve is

```
var myObject {
  id1 : { 
    name:place_name,
    location : place_loc
  },
  id2 : { 
    name:place_name,
    location : place_loc
  },
  id3 : { 
    name:place_name,
    location : place_loc
  }
}
```

What I want to do is that Initially I want the properties "id1", "id2".. to be dynamic. And then dynamically assign name:place_name and other properties of each property.

I dont know the number of properties (id1,id2,id3...) hence would like to add them dynamically and following the addition of properties(id1,id2... ) I want to dynamically add the property values. (place_name & place_loc) of each id.

My code looks something like this.

```
var myObject = {};
myObject[idnumber1].place = "SomePlace1";
myObject[idnumber1].place = "SomeLoc1";
myObject[idnumber2].place = "SomePlace1";
myObject[idnumber2].place = "SomeLoc1";
```

But it gives error.

I know it seems simple doubt but any help would be grateful.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set a value of already assigned objects at keys "`idnumber1`", etc.

What you'll need is to initialize each objects for your ids like this:

```
var myObject = {};
myObject[idnumber1] = {};
myObject[idnumber1].place = "SomePlace1";
myObject[idnumber2] = {};
myObject[idnumber2].place = "SomeLoc1"
```

Comment: Or better:
`myObject[idnumber1] = {
  place: "SomePlace1"
}`

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way, it's not exactly what you did ask for, but I think it will become easier to change this later on.

```
function Place(name, location) {
    this.name = name;
    this.location = location;
}

var myObject = {}
myObject['id1'] = new Place('Foo', 'Bar');
myObject['id2'] = new Place('Internet', 'test');
console.log(myObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically create objects in your collection, you can use a numerical counter variable to create your object collection (`myObject["id" + i] = {name: place_name, location: place_loc}`).

An example:

```
var myObject = {};
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    myObject["id" + i] = {name: place_name, location: place_loc}
}
```

In practice, you can use a counter that you increment outside of a loop.